# ConstraintLayout inside DrawerLayout causes some problems

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, drawerlayout

I am working on an app that uses a DrawerLayout. The fragment containing this layout also contains some scrollable content.

So the main layout of this fragment is a `DrawerLayout`, below is the include block for the `app bar`, then the `ScrollView` block, which contains a `ConstraintLayout` so that I can put all the content I need in the `ScrollView`. Here is the code in details :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appBarMain"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewDashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytDashboardContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="76dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAwaitingReview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_color_primary"
                android:text="42 avis en attente"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.lsjwzh.widget.recyclerviewpager.RecyclerViewPager
                android:id="@+id/rvpPlaceOfTheDay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAwaitingReview"
                app:rvp_singlePageFling="true"
                app:rvp_triggerOffset="0.1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblDateNews"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="Dimanche 31 Fevrier"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvpPlaceOfTheDay" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblDateNews" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvNews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/separator" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/fragment_dashboard_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But there are two problems :

- The first is that the `NavigationDrawer` button at the top left is no more clickable. I know that this is caused by the `ConstraintLayout` because I tried putting every element as a comment one by one, and it worked properly as long as I uncommented the `ConstraintLayout`, but I couldn't find a way to solve it.
- And the second is that the `ScrollView` scrolls over the `app bar` as you can see on this screenshot. For this one I couldn't figure out the source of the problem...

[image: ScrollView scrolling over app bar]

Comment: Your `DrawerLayout` should have only one main content `View`. The `ScrollView` needs to be in the `app_bar_main` layout, or an `<include>`d layout therein, somewhere. As you have it now, the `ScrollView` is completely covering `app_bar_main`, which is why it's over the `Toolbar`, and the toggle button doesn't work.

Comment: Wow thank you so much now I clearly see my mistake. I moved my `ScrollView` inside the `AppBarLayout` in `app_bar_main` and now both problems are solved. But isn't it weird to do it this way ? I mean is it the right way to do it or just a workaround ? Because in my `DashboardFragment`, I am inflating `fragment_dashboard` which now just contains a `DrawerLayout` and and include to `app_bar_main` which contains the content of the Dashboard...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concern, but it's not just a workaround. That's how `DrawerLayout` is meant to be set up. The `<include>` tag just makes it easier to modularize and reuse layouts. You could actually put everything directly inside the layout you've posted (as long as there's only one main content `View`), and it would be the same thing after inflation.

Comment: Alright thanks ! Yeah I just found it weird to put the content of my dashboard not directly inside its dedicated layout, but if it's how it's meant to be that is perfect then :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure why the default templates split everything into multiple layouts that usually only end up being used once, but that's just how they did it. You certainly could combine those all into one, if you find it easier to manage. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) I solved my problems, so my mistake was to put my `ScrollView` after I included the `app_bar_main`, which ended up covering it, so the solution was to simply move the `ScrollView` in `app_bar_main`, after the `AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but my guess is:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewDashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

It that won't help try wrapping ScrollView with eg. LinearLayout.

Hope it helps.